# How to find Ajaxfileupload control inside Listview When in Editmode

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to find ajaxcontroltoolkit:ajaxfileupload which is placed inside a ListView in EditItemTemplate mode.
I need to say i already tried to find this control in my ListView in these two events without result: ItemEditing and ItemDataBound.
Should I forget to use ajaxfileupload inside ListView or GridView? or is there any solution for this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

Try the `TemplateControl` property:

```
ListView1.TemplateControl.FindControl("contrlID");
```

Comment: I handled it another way outside the ListView... and its work fine now. But actually its not accessable within a Listview in EditItem mode for sure.